# How costly is it to put a middleware in django

Tags: django, web-applications, architecture, django-middleware

I have written for a very simple app of mine .

1. To login facebook canvas users of the app
2. To do some visitor tracking , most of the code is very simple.

The app probably is not that complicated , fairly close to a blogging system . However I wish to know how costly in terms of resources my architecture of middleware going to be.

One of things that is specifically worrying me is the fact that a new visitor object is created every time a unique request is made . Is that a good idea ?

So while middleware are an amazing DRY and agile concept how well do they standout in terms of performance.

Thanks

Comment: Try it! If there are performance issues then think about how to fix them. You can spend a lot of time figuring out the what-if's but it's easier to do it, see if it's a problem and then address it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I can't serve you with benchmarks, my experience is that, if a middleware is thin, it does not really matter in terms of performance, at least if you're not running a really high-traffic site. In my projects (some of them middle-traffic sites), I make heavy use of middleware, and I did not notice a remarkable performance drawbacks.

About the "visitor object": If you are using sessions, Django initializes a user object on every request, independently of using a middleware or not. Even if the user has not been logged in, an anonymous user will be created.

So keep your middleware small and you might not get into trouble.